# "manage.py startapp" doesn't create db.sqlite3

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm following an online tutorial in order to learn Django/Python. I'm using PyCharm Community Edition as my IDE. On Windows 10.

When I run `python manage.py startapp myapp` at the `(venv)` prompt in terminal window , no error is shown, and `\myapp` folder is created with the expected content. However, the file `db.sqlite3` is **not** created, and I can't follow through the rest of the tutorial.

What might be going wrong here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *What might be going wrong here?* - exactly. If there are no error messages, crashes, what indicates that something is wrong and the unnamed tutorial can not be followed through afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you start a new django app no database must created.

you can run command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

to generate database for your project.

default database is sqlite and stored in file named `db.sqlite3`

Answer (score 2):

Command `python manage.py startapp myapp` does not create `db.sqlite3`.

Run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

It will automatically create one if not present.